# Firebase Cloud Firestore PHP read large amount of data

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, large-data

i have a large amount of record (~1000 - 10000). I need to fetch this all data and display it. I am using the cloud firestore php. I faced one issue it, it was very slow to get the data, sometimes it will get the requested timeout error message. I wonder if there have the better way / effective way to handle this large amount of data.

Plus, i have some nested query. and my purpose of use is to export this large amount of data to the excel file.
Here is the some part of my code for reference.

```
$query = $firestore->collection('history')->where('token', '==', $token)->where('Date', '<', $end)->where('Date', '>', $start)->documents();

$data1 = [];
$data2 = [];
$data3 = [];

foreach ($query as $document) {
  $i = $i +1;

  $query1 = $firestore->collection("user")->where("id","==",$document['id'])->documents();
  foreach ($query1 as $query1) {
    array_push($data1,$query1['name']);
  }

  $query2 = $firestore->collection("userdetails")->where("id","==",$document['id'])->documents();
  foreach ($query2 as $query2) {
    array_push($data2,$query2['name']);
  }

  $query3 = $firestore->collection("dataprefrences")->where("id","==",$document['id'])->documents();
  foreach ($query3 as $query3) {
    array_push($data3,$query3['name']);
  }
}
```

Comment: For clarity, 10,000 documents is not a large amount of data to Firestore. 1,000,000 would be a larger amount of data but nothing Firestore can't handle. The timeouts more likely have to do with how the code is implemented. Also can you clarify *very slow to get the data*? What portion is very slow and most importantly, what are you expecting from the code in the question?

Comment: @Jay, the part of the code above is how i implement the code. What i think for slow to get the data is, i need to wait more than 10 sec to get the respond from firebase. Of course, for more than 1000 documents, it take more longer time, and sometimes it return timeout. I am expecting that someone will give me a good advise on how to handle those large data. Or there has another way to handle this situation.Thanks

Comment: We retrieve 10,000 documents in .93 (sometimes less) seconds on a continual basis. That being said, we don't know what's in *your* documents vs whats in ours so we need to understand what's taking so long for your use case. The code in your question is a big loop (which should probably be avoided) so it's not clear what you're expecting or why you're doing that. Can you clarify your structure and what the expected result is from that code? e.g. why aren't you just querying everything from the 'history' collection for user1, 2, or 3 to start with?

Comment: My documents contain the basic information, which is date,time, and the id. I wanna get the information from another collections, and display it together with the main query. Hmmm, i know this might be a issue for NoSQL structure. But i cant change the structure So i am finding another way to solve it.

Comment: I am editing my question, to make it clear.

Comment: @Jay you said you getting 10k documents within 1 seconds!!, but for 15,000 documents retrieving it's taking more than 40 seconds from my php script in laravel, in a document i have 10-15 simple fields. Which php library you using ?? I am using [this library](https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase) in my laravel site, my code like this - `$firestore = app('firebase.firestore'); $database = $firestore->database(); $doctorColl = $database->collection('visits'); $doctorDocuments = $doctorColl->documents();` what's wrong that it's taking too much time?? plz help me if you can

Comment: @developer I would like to help but we only code in Swift to that's all I can address. Your times are way higher than they should be - that could be an internet connection or network issue causing the delays. It could also be a coding issue so you should do some research to determine your overall network speed to ensure it's good, and then if so, post a question with the code you're using and the expected results.

Comment: @Jay no internet problem bcoz it's happening always even in US, what kind of network issue you saying?. I already posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311980/firebase-firestore-documents-retrieving-and-parsing-became-very-slow-in-laravel). I checked how much time a php script takes and found that document retrieving call taking all that huge time, and after documents retrieved the looping script took only 1 second. I need to understand why. firebase help pages only say alternatives to overcome this.

Comment: @developer to be clear - we read 10,000 nodes on a regular basis and after the initial load we see the load times I mentioned. Even at that, the initial load comes in about 4 seconds.