# firebase firestore documents retrieving and parsing became very slow in laravel php library

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, caching, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching firebase firestore database data in my laravel project, I am using kreait/laravel-firebase package for this purpose. By the following way i am fetching firestore collection and documents to work with

```
$firestore = app('firebase.firestore');
$db = $firestore->database();
$doctorRef = $db->collection('users');

$data['users'] = $doctorRef->documents();
```

There are around 4000 documents in this users collection and more will grow in future, and i am seeing that it's taking too much time when I load the page which holds these fetching codes. So look like query became slow because of huge documents retrieving and parsing.

Or can it be that firestore offline caching making things slow?? if yes then how do i test it by disabling offline cache if it's being used in this php library package of laravel? I did not find any methods yet, i need to verify it.

I searched google but so far did not get any solutions, like [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#web) of offline cache shows examples in web but not in php codes.

My concern is why fetching firestore data is very slow when there are more than 3k documents? is this for offline cache or for what other reasons?. FYI if i put limit in the query then slowness reduces. Please write some details with examples if possible, not one or two lines. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anybody plz? at least confirm me how to disable offline caching if used in that php library

Comment: It's not for offline caching, you are requesting all documents of the collection and that's why all of them are downloaded 

You could use paginated queries, limit the results with filters and/or just load the fields that you need for a particular operation (with `select`) to reduce the amount of data that needs to be fetched. https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.19.1/firestore/firestoreclient?method=collection

Comment: In testing (Swift) we initially read 5k documents in around 4 seconds. All reads of 5k documents after that range between .39s and .72s. I question why you're reading in 5k nodes at a time though - that could be a design issue. What's the purpose?

Comment: @Jay When i posted this question it was 5k docs, now 15k. Actually I need 15k documents in one call, it's the must requirement to work with those data and calculation. many guys suggesting paging. But is it normal that 15k docs takes that much time around 40 seconds?! I checked php script time, fetching data from firestore taking all times, and looping those 15k in php takes only 1 second.

Comment: I don't know your use case but be careful about loading large amounts of data - it can overwhelm the device and cause it to crash. You should be able to load 15k documents in a much shorter time than that - at least that's been our experience and loads after the initial one happen instantly. You may want to consider paginating your data or changing how your data is structured to reduce loading times.

Comment: I used firebase javascript sdk and seeing that it fetching faster than that php library i am using. So why php library taking so long when fetching documents from firestore, are there any configs i am missing? php kreait/laravel-firebase package documentation is less. anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @jeromegamez, what is causing the page to load slowly is that you are retrieving all the documents (>4 000 ) when you use :

```
$doctorRef = $db->collection('users'); 
$data['users'] = $doctorRef->documents();
```

To reduce the amount of results you get, [you can order the documents and set a limit to it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data):

```
$doctorRef = $db->collection('users'); 
$query = $doctorRef->orderBy('ID')->limit(SOMENUMBER);
$documents = $query->documents();
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to gradually continue to fetch more results after the first set. You can do that [using pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query):

```
$lastID = 0;
foreach ($documents as $document) {
    $lastID = $document['ID'];
}

$nextQuery = $doctorRef->orderBy('ID')->startAfter([$lastID]);
$nextDocuments = $nextQuery->documents();
```

Comment: if i fetch using document id you showed then results may differ because of rearrangements of documents in the collection, don't know how but [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU&t=446s) explained.

Comment: Am i right about document rearrangements within collection? so for that if i use startafter with doc id then things may not go right way.

Comment: This is not correct. The video talks about real-time listeners, which your app is not doing, since it's just querying the DB every request. In your case, pagination would work well. Since you're getting docs starting at the previous last doc ID, it means that any addition would not matter. You're not starting "200 positions from the start", but rather "starting on the last point", which is exactly what you want.